# Instance of one function should inherit from instance of other function - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose there are 2 functions `A()` and `B()`:

```
var A = function() {
    this.name = 'test'
}
A.prototype.showName() = {
    console.log(this.name)
}

var B = function() {
    this.age = 10
}
B.prototype.showAge() = {
    console.log(this.age)
}

var a = new A();

var b = new B();
```

what I require is the instance of `B()` should inherit from instance of `A()`

Note: instance of `B()` should still have a function `showAge()`

Comment: You should read the [MDN inheritance documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance).

Comment: Use classes in es6 instead

Comment: Your note makes no sense. What made you think  that instance of `B` loose the function `showAge()`?

Comment: `B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);` should do it.

Comment: No, an instance pretty much never should inherit from another instance. It should inherit from a prototype object.